# Lagrangian mechanics and geodesics in configuration space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-principle, geodesics

In lagrangian mechanics Is the path that take a System in the configuration space between initial and final state is identical to the geodesic which connect the two points?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Can Lagrangian be thought of as a metric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105726/2451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will depend upon the details of the actual action. In many common cases it will be.

Moreover, we require the configuration manifold to be at least a pseudo-Riemannian manifold in order to even define the notion of a geodesic.